# How to enable tabs as character in a Silverlight RichTextControl?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, richtextbox

I looked online and it seems to support tabs as characters but when I press the `Tab` key, nothing happens. `RichTextBox` is the only control in my application so I don't want to have the `Tab` to change focus but to insert tab characters into the editor.

Is there a property I need to set to enable this?

Comment: are you saying that when you hit the TAB key you want to insert #9

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But I am looking to get standard text editor functionality with the tab key.

Comment: @DJKRAZE a `TextBlock`? For **editable rich text?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how I see it, theres currently no built-in functionality for this, but you *can* do it yourself:

```
private void RichTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox = (RichTextBox) sender;
        richTextBox.Selection.Select(richTextBox.ContentEnd, richTextBox.ContentEnd);
        Run tab = new Run() {Text = "\t"};
        richTextBox.Selection.Insert(tab);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, all this clutter *is* necessary to emulate the `AcceptsTab` property that is provided in WPF. The above techinque sets the selection to the end of the `RichTextBox` content and then inserts a new `Run`(inline text element) at that position.

I've tested it in-browser and it should work for you, too. Let me know if there's anything left to clarify.

Comment: Thanks just tested it, works great. You know this stuff obviously :O

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any direct way at the moment but you can always do

```
  private void RichTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
                rich.AppendText("    ");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, would append insert the text or just append it at the end of the textbox?

Comment: According to MSDN it `Appends a string to the contents of a text control.`

Comment: You will also have to manually increase the cursor/Caret position I guess

Comment: AppendText does not exist on the Silverlight version of `RichTextBox` - it only exists on the WPF version. This answer is **wrong**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Support SHIFT+TAB as well.

```
private void txtText_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if ((System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers & System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0)
        {
            var startSel = txtText.Selection.Start;
            var endSel = txtText.Selection.End;

            var backwardPosition = txtText.Selection.Start.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
            if (backwardPosition != null)
            {
                txtText.Selection.Select(backwardPosition, txtText.Selection.Start);
                var c = txtText.Selection.Text;
                if (c.Equals("\t"))
                {
                    txtText.Selection.Select(backwardPosition, endSel);
                    txtText.Selection.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtText.Selection.Select(startSel, endSel);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtText.Selection.Insert(new Run() { Text = "\t" });
        }
    }
}
```